# NativeScript iOS: release build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I want to update my app that is currently in AppStore. So I logged in into apple developer and downloaded the certificate from there (which is not expired yet).

What do I have now:

- The certificate file $my_certificatename.cer
- I still have a .p12-file in my project directory, which (I thought) should be the corresponding private key.
- The following build.xcconfig:

  `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = $my_certificatename;
   DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = $my_TeamID;
   ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
   ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;`
- updated version numbers in my `Info.plist`

Then I tried to run the following command:

```
tns build ios --release --for-device
```

Which does some stuff and then displays the following error:

```
    ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

2017-09-19 12:35:15.309 xcodebuild[3302:410544] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/nl/z3cdbrb17776dtxlltdqvc4h0000gn/T/HandyApp_2017-09-19_12-35-15.308.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-09-19 12:35:17.352 xcodebuild[3302:410544] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f8964985730>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

** EXPORT FAILED **

Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70
# build ios
```

Did I miss something in my configuration? Can anyone relate to this error?

My Xcode Signing Identities of my Account:

[image: Signing Identities]

Comment: I would suggest that set certificates from xCode and try to create build from same.

Comment: Since this is an update I thought I would need exactly the certificates that were used when deploying (and which are shown on apple.developer.com)

Comment: If certificates are valid and not expired then you can use same.

Comment: What i used to was set certificates from xCode and generate build from CLI.

Comment: They are valid and not expired - I update my post to what I can see on Xcode signing Identities - is that what you meant? @HardikVaghani

Comment: Try just `tns build ios --for-device`

Comment: Rüdiger, did you find solution?